# Working mongo references with html forms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms, express, mongoose-schema

I'm working with a form and two database collections, when the form is submitted all the data from the input elements is stored in the corresponding collection. This is pretty easy to do setting input name attributes like `blogs[content]` and then using that object in the route which sends the data to the database with `.create()`.

However, I have no idea how to do this when a collection has a reference to another one.

Let's say I have the following collections:

```
var Blog = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String,
    authors: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Author"
    }]
});

var Author = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
```

I know you can associate the data with the `push()` function straight from the routes, but I want to do it from the form itself.

How can I send data to the `authors` reference inside `Blog` from the `form`? I tried setting the name of the input as `blogs[authors]` but that doesn't work, guess is not that simple.

Is it even possible? Or is pushing from the routes the only option?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I was asked for the routes code so here it is

```
app.get("/form", function(req, res){
    Author.find({}, function(err, authors) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);

        else
            res.render("form.ejs", {authors: authors});
    });
});

// form.ejs sends a POST request to /blogs

app.post("/blogs", function(req, res){
    Blog.create(req.body.blogs, function(err, newBlog){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.redirect("/form");
    });
});
```

The HTML form would be something like this:

```
<form action="/blogs" method="POST">
    <select name=" HERE GOES THE name ATTRIBUTE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO SET ">
        <option value="0" selected>Authors</option>

        <% authors.forEach(function(author){ %>
            <option value="<%= author._id %>"><%= author.name %></option>
        <% }) %>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I could solve it in the end. Looks like it was a mistake trying to save something directly into the collection's reference from the `form`, I had to first store it in a separate variable like this:

```
var variableName = req.body.inputName;
```

And then loop through it pushing all the values into the collection's reference from the route, so in the end looks like pushing from the routes is the only option.